# Dictionary of lists to (flattened) List

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `<MyKey, List<MyClass>>` and a List of type `MyClass`. Now I want to check if there are elements within the latter that are not contained in any of the lists within the dictionary. My first approach was on nesting two loops (one for the actual list, one for the lists within the dictionary). If an item was found I may break the inner loop and continue with next element in outer loop.

```
foreach (MyClass feature in features)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (var kv in this._features)  // this._features is the dictionary
    {
        if (kv.Value.Contains(feature))
        {
            found = true;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (!found) result.Add(feature);
}
```

This works so far, but I´d prefer a shorter approach for this, probably using LINQ. I think it may work if I flatten the values of the dictionary into one single list, but I have no clue on how to achieve this.

Comment: You could probably do something using Select(), SelectMany() and Where(), can you share what you have tried? Why do you want to shorten this working code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten your values into a `IEnumerable<MyClass>` then use `Except` to get differences:

```
var differentElements = this._features.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Except(features);
result.AddRange(differentElements);
```

This might not work as expected if `MyClass` doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` properly.

Comment: Wow, this seems to do what I need. Thanks

Comment: Well, I think I have to change the order of your expressions a bit, since I want to select those elements from the features-list that are not contained in the dictionary, I suppose the way you wrote it performs the check for elements in the dictionary that are not within the list.